# Date function without updating according to current date on recalculation

Tags: excel

```
ENTRY DATE           DES          AMOUNT
1-Oct-14              A            100
3-Oct-14              B             50
4-Oct-14              M             25
8-Oct-14              F             25
```

i have formatted entry date column by used this function:

```
=IF(B2&C2="", " ", TODAY())
```

The problem is once i make a new entry each entry date is updated automatically  according to current date. so I wanted previous entry date should not be changed

Comment: Select, Copy, Paste special, Values.

Comment: http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/01/08/timestamps-excel-formula-help/

Answer (score 0):

If you've reviewed the article noted above you should have a good idea of what is required for generating a static date/time *stamp* into your input worksheet. Here is an example that will survive copying many values into columns B & C as well as controlling any errors that might arise.

To incorporate this into your input worksheet right-click the worksheet's name tab at the bottom and choose `View Code`. When the VBE opens, paste the following into the pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 - (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B:C")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo FallThrough
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Columns("B:C"))
            If Application.IsText(Cells(t.Row, 2)) And _
              IsNumeric(Cells(t.Row, 3)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(t.Row, 3)) Then
                Cells(t.Row, 2) = UCase(Cells(t.Row, 2).Value)
                Cells(t.Row, 1) = Date
                'Cells(t.Row, 1) = now
            Else
                Cells(t.Row, 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next t
    End If
FallThrough:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tap `Alt+Q` to return to your worksheet. You can commence inputting *DES* and *Amount* values immediately.

I've included a commented line that puts the date and time into column A rather than just the date. If you choose to use it (remove the single quote), remove the line above it that only puts hte date in.

Comment: I got what i have expected but when i close the workbook its not working. any solution

Comment: @yogogeri - If you added the above code to a worksheet code sheet then the workbook would have to be saved as either a *macro-enabled workbook* or a *binary workbook*. Standard workbooks (XLSX) cannot retain macro code or VBA projects. FWIW, you should have been warned about this when you saved the workbook and closed it.